# Extract values from column based on other column EXcel function line code

Tags: excel

New to Excel : Problem

Sample table Below :

```
Company |   Product |       |Total Sales
AAA     QQQ     123
BBB     QQQ     140
CCC     WWW     127
DDD     WWW     145
CCC     QQQ     190
DDD     QQQ     290
AAA     WWW     240
BBB     WWW     120
AAA     RRR     123
BBB     RRR     122
CCC     RRR     178
DDD     RRR     789
```

Desired output : Same Table should be sorted by companies and products arranged according to total sales: 
(Company names need not to be sorted but should be clumped together)

Desired output:

```
Company     Product     Total Sales
AAA     WWW     240
AAA     QQQ     123
AAA     RRR     123
BBB     QQQ     140
BBB     RRR     122
BBB     WWW     120
CCC     QQQ     190
CCC     RRR     178
CCC     WWW     127
DDD     QQQ     290
DDD     RRR     789
DDD     WWW     145
```

The sheet is too big to do it manually. Is there any way to automate the process in excel . If so Please help. Solution should be by functions only no pivot table or VBA.

Comment: show us the code you have tried, so that we can guide you or assist you.

Comment: Use Sort: Sort by Company A to Z, Then by Sales Larges to Smallest. Doesn't this work? Am I missing something here? Which will sort your original table in-place... same as your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that all you want to do is sort your data on the `Company` and `Total Sales` columns, in that order.  In this case, you can just highlight your table in Excel and then press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. This will bring up a sorting dialog box, as the screen capture below shows.  Note: include the column headers when you select the data (despite what the screen capture shows).

[image]

Just choose `Company` as the first sort column, with ascending order (i.e. `A to Z`, which is the default).  Then click `Add Level` to add a new sort column, and choose `Total Sales` with `Largest to Smallest` for the sort order.

Comment: Is it possible to do Via command functions ...I can use any no of sheets

Comment: You can also click `Data -> Sort` from the top menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use Excel menu Data >> Filter

[image: Data >> Filter]

select arrow button on header row then select sort type as you wish.

[image]

Or you need more sort select like below picture.

[image]

Add level and select column which you would like to sort then click OK.

[image]

The result should be like this.

[image]